# QGIS pie chart with only one attribute displaying distinct values

Tags: qgis, chart

In QGIS I have a map with several counties areas. Each county area has a road network split into segments. I have an attribute grading each segement quality with a note raging from 1 to 5.
For each county I would like to have a pie chart showing the proportion of each note (1 to 5) in percentages compared to the total length of the county's road network.